# SUM time in varchar/nvarchar data type field

Tags: sql, time, sum, varchar, nvarchar

I have troubles to SUM time in a varchar/nvarchar data type field.

This is the format what I'm trying to SUM: (HH:mm:ss)

Comment: what error u r getting???

Comment: Why are you not using a TIME data type field for this?

Comment: The database was designed a couple of years ago, I really don't know why they have chosen for nvarchar data type field.

This is what I've tried: 
select convert(nvarchar(255),dateadd(second,SUM ( DATEPART(hh,(convert(time,[column],1))) * 3600 FROM [table]

The error I get is a syntax error where a operator is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out:

```
select convert(decimal(18, 2), convert(decimal(18, 2), ppt.hour) + convert(decimal(18, 2), convert(decimal(18, 2), ppt.minute/ 60)) + convert(decimal(18, 2), convert(decimal(18, 2), ppt.second / 3600))) AS Hours, ppt.[column] from (select SUM(convert(decimal(2),left([column], 2))) AS hour, SUM(convert(decimal(2), left(right([column], 5), 2))) AS minute, SUM(convert(decimal(2), right([column], 2))) AS second, [column] FROM [table] GROUP BY [column]) AS ppt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
create table tblTime (dt datetime)
insert tblTime values
  ('00:25:00'),
  ('00:20:00')
```

Here is the calculation:

```
Select cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))/3600 as varchar(12)) + ':' + 
            right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))/60%60 as varchar(2)),2) +
            ':' + right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,dt))%60 as varchar(2)),2)
from tblTime
```

Output: `0:45:00`

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b61f/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @time1 varchar(8) = '00:25:00';
declare @time2 varchar(8) = '00:20:00';

select CONVERT(varchar(8),
                  DATEADD (SECOND ,
                 (CONVERT(int, LEFT(@time1, 2))*60*60  /* hours in seconds*/ 
                 + CONVERT(int, substring(@time1,4,2)*60) /* minutes in seconds*/
                 + CONVERT(int, RIGHT(@time1, 2)))/* seconds only */
                 , '19000101 ' + @time2
                ) 
               ,108)/* convert back to time format*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try as,

```
create table timeSum (value1 varchar(50), value3 varchar(50))

insert into timeSum values ('00:45', '00:10')
```

**Calculation**

```
select Convert(Varchar,(Convert(DateTime,Value1 )+Convert(DateTime,value3)),114) as TotalTime from timeSum
```

> **Out Put**: 00:55:00:000

**Remarks :**

- I recommended you to use DateTime or Time datatype for in Date or Time related field.